# How could I split a string after the n-th field and create an array from the remaining parts in PHP?

Tags: php, arrays, string

I have the following string:

```
*/3 * * * * echo yes
```

What I want to do is to create an array with 2 elements from that, where the elements are separated after the 5th field from each other:

```
$result = [ "*/3 * * * *", "echo yes" ];
```

In Linux `bash` shell I would have just used:

```
echo "*/3 * * * * logger yes" | cut -d' ' -f1-5
echo "*/3 * * * * logger yes" | cut -d' ' -f6-
```

As you can see it's an cron-entry. So writing a RegEx would be rather inconvenient as the fields can change. Ok, I could write a RegEx which splits the elements from each other with a whitespace delimiter, but I'm wondering is there any function in PHP which is similar too GNU `cut` or `awk`, which I could use for that which splits the two parts after the 5th field.

How could I achieve the same result with PHP?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this :

```
$result = [
   implode('', array_slice(explode(' ', $string), 0, 5),
   implode('', array_slice(explode(' ', $string), 5)
];
```

Answer (score 2):

The *very* first step in attempting to parse anything is to understand the grammar of the thing you are trying to parse. If you can't define this then anything you do subsequently will fail. Providing only one or 2 examples in the absence of a definition would be grounds for closing your question, however it does look very like a [crontab file](https://linux.die.net/man/5/crontab). The grammar of this is very well defined, but it doesn't work the way you think it does.

- Fields are not seperated by " " but by a variable amount of whitespace
- there may be leading whitespace before the first character
- there are always 6 fields
- all the fields can be variable length and contain (almost) any printable ASCII charts
- the 6th field can contain embedded and unescaped white space

Your cut method does not parse this grammar correctly.

You can parse it with a regex:

```
if (preg_match('/^(\s*\S+)(\s+\S+)(\s+\S+)(\s+\S+)(\s+\S+)(\s+.+)$/', $str, $match)) {
    print_r($match);
} else {
    print "invalid";
}
```

It should be obvious from the output how to then create your array.

Comment: The OP wrote “As you can see it's an cron-entry”. Writing “it does look very like a crontab file” is a bit strange since there's no doubt.

Answer (score 1):

The [`explode()`](http://php.net/manual/function.explode.php), [`array_slice()`](http://php.net/manual/function.array-slice.php) and [`implode()`](http://php.net/manual/function.implode.php) functions used together will work similarly to the `cut` tool.

You can use it to split the string into an array:

```
$line = '*/3 * * * * echo yes';

$parts = explode(' ', $line);
```

Then you can use `array_slice()` in order to extract the schedule and the command, and `implode()` to transform arrays into strings:

```
$schedule = implode(' ', array_slice($parts, 0, 5));

$command = implode(' ', array_slice($parts, 5));

print $schedule.PHP_EOL.$command;
```

It will show:

```
*/3 * * * *
echo yes
```

Try it yourself: https://3v4l.org/sW7VJ